# Sitecore Programmatically Hide Item

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

How can I programmatically hide an item in sitecore:

Heres what I have tried so far:

```
Item recordDetails = root.Add(object.Name + " Details", folderTemplate);
recordDetails.Fields.ReadAll(); 
recordDetails.Editing.BeginEdit();
CheckboxField recordHidden = recordDetails.Fields["Hidden"];//Also tried "isHidden"
if (recordHidden != null)
{
   recordHidden.Checked = true;
}
recordDetails.Editing.EndEdit();
```

But no luck, any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can also use `myItem.Appearance.Hidden = true;` :)

Answer (score 2):

The field name I was using was incorrect - it was "__Hidden". Changing that fixed the issue.